# How to integrate SAP Cloud Platform TMS to CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: sap-cloud-platform, sap-cloud-foundry

We are trying to implement SAP Cloud Platform Transport Management service in our current CI/CD pipeline (Piper Project).
We are referring to documentation in https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/scenarios/TMS_Extension/ for the configuration details.
Appreciate if someone can answer the below questions.

1. Which parameter should we configure in tmsUpload step for the Transport Management service end-point? (The only parameters we can see in the above documentation are credentialsId, nodeName and mtaPath)
2. As we understand, credentialsId needs to be configured in Jenkins. But what credentials should we configure for tmsUpload? We tried with the service clientid, verificationkey and clientsecret but neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am quite late but for future users who dont figure it out.

1. The parameters required are listed at this site :
   https://sap.github.io/jenkins-library/steps/tmsUpload/

2. For tmsUpload credentials you have to create a service key on your SAP TMS account. It would be a JSON file. After creating the file, create jenkins credentials of type secret text and paste the entire content of the JSON file in the secret text. Assign a CredentialID to this secret text and provide it in the credentialsid parameter of the tmsUpload step in your pipeline config file.

Hope this helps your problem.